# Check if Field Name is zero

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to make a `if` condition which will check the value of the field name or if the fieldname is less than or equal to the number that the user had given so that the value of the data field will not be equal to `negative`. My problem is how can I declare a field name on an `if` condition? Please be kind and feel free to edit my question.

Here's the coding:

```
if (reader.Read())
   {
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set 
Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");
   cmd.Connection = con;

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Quantity));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", row.Item);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("You added " + row.Quantity + " " + row.Product, "Existing Item");
}
```

**EDIT**

The input quantity will be subtracted from the `field Quantity`

**UPDATE**

what I had tried so far:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Quantity));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", row.Item);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);
int intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Quantity);
   if (Convert.ToInt32("@Quantity") >= intQuantity)
   {
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("Congrats");
   ...
```

and said that the input string was not in correct format. The field `Quantity` is in a `text form.`

Comment: What do you mean equal to negative? What field do you want to compare?

Comment: Because when the user input a value which is higher than the value of the ``Quantity field`` the update value of the ``Quantity`` will be negative

Answer (score 0):

This code checks whether `Quantity` is greater than or equal to `row.Quantity`.

```
if (reader.Read())
{
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set 
   Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");
   cmd.Connection = con;

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Quantity));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", row.Item);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);

   if (Quantity >= Convert.ToInt32(row.Quantity))
   {
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       MessageBox.Show("You added " + row.Quantity + " " + row.Product, "Existing Item");
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Quantity must not be negative.");
   }
}
```

If this isn't what you wanted, please let me know.

Comment: sir it must be `Quantity >= row.Quantity` but how could I do that?

Comment: I changed the `if` clause for this, assuming that `Quantity` is a local variable, field, or parameter. If it's not, just put whatever the quantity is in that location.

Comment: The name `Quantity` does not exist in the current context

Comment: Where is the Quantity value coming from, then?